# How do I use perl-rename to replace . with _ on linux recursively, except for extensions

Tags: linux, command, rename

I am trying to rename some files and folders recursively to format the names, and figured `find` and `perl-rename` might be the tools for it. I've managed to find most of the commands I want to run, but for the last two:

- I would like for every `.` in a directory name to be replaced by `_` and
- for every `.` but the last in a file name to be replaced with `_`

So that `./my.directory/my.file.extension` becomes `./my_directory/my_file.extension`.

For the second task, I don't even have a command.

For the first task, I have the following command :
`find . -type d -depth -exec perl-rename -n "s/([^^])\./_/g" {} +`
Which renames `./the_expanse/Season 1/The.Expanse.S01E01.1080p.WEB-DL.DD5.1.H264-RARBG` `./the_expanse/Season 1/Th_Expans_S01E0_1080_WEB-D_DD__H264-RARBG`, so it doesn't work because each word character before an `.` is eaten.

If instead type :
`find . -type d -depth -exec perl-rename -n "s/\./_/g" {} +`, I rename `./the_expanse/Season 1/The.Expanse.S01E01.1080p.WEB-DL.DD5.1.H264-RARBG` into `_/the_expanse/Season 1/The_Expanse_S01E01_1080p_WEB-DL_DD5_1_H264-RARBG` which doesn't work either because the current directory is replaced by `_`.

If someone could give me a solution to:

- replace every `.` in a directory name by `_` and
- replace every `.` but the last in a file name with `_`
  I'd be very grateful.

Comment: I think if you read the details on how find works you’ll be able to adjust your second command to do what you want. Something like passing some values to the -name flag to find only the directories that aren’t the “.” Directory should work.

Answer (score 0):

**First** tackling the directories with `.`

```
# find all directories and remove the './' part of each and save to a file
$ find -type d  | perl -lpe  's@^(\./|\.)@@g' > list-all-dir
# 
# dry run
# just print the result without actual renaming 
$ perl -lne '($old=$_) && s/\./_/g && print' list-all-dir
#
# if it looked fine, rename them
$ perl -lne '($old=$_) && s/\./_/g && rename($old,$_)' list-all-dir
```

This part `s/\./_/g` is for matching every `.` and replacing it with `_`

---

**Second** tackling the file extensions, rename `.` except `.` for file extension

```
# find all *.txt file and save or your match
$ find -type f -name \*.txt  | perl -lpe  's@^(\./|\.)@@g' > list-all-file
#
# dry run
$ perl -lne '($old=$_) && s/(?:(?!\.txt$)\.)+/_/g && print ' list-all-file
#
# if it looked fine, rename them
$ perl -lne '($old=$_) && s/(?:(?!\.txt$)\.)+/_/g && rename($old,$_) ' list-all-file
```

This part `(?:(?!\.txt$)\.)+` is for matching every `.` except the last `.` before the file extension.

---

**NOTE**

Here I used `.txt` and you should replace it with your match. The **Second** code will rename input like this:

```
/one.one/one.one/one.file.txt
/two.two/two.two/one.file.txt
/three.three/three.three/one.file.txt
```

to such an output:

```
/one_one/one_one/one_file.txt
/two_two/two_two/one_file.txt
/three_three/three_three/one_file.txt
```

and you can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/5O7CJq/1) with an online regex match.